# "Wait on" vs "wait for"

Tags: meaning

I've just heard

> your sister is waiting on you

with the meaning of *wait for* (as in *wait for the bus*).

Up to now I had only encountered *wait on* with the meaning of *attend to* / *serve*.

1. Is this use of *wait on* instead of *wait for* widely spread in the English speaking world or more specific to certain geographical areas?
2. In the sentence I'm quoting above, and without further context, could there be any ambiguity as to the meaning?

Comment: To be pedantic, it could also mean that you and your sister were both waiting, and she was doing it while sitting on your shoulders.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rdOz1EihRV4

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's regional in U.S. English. Much of the U.S. says "waiting for you", but I believe that much of the South says "waiting on you". I don't know exactly what regions use "wait on" (not the Northeast), and a couple of minutes of Googling didn't find any answers, so I can't be more specific.

Comment: You are correct, despite lack of Googling evidence. "Wait on" is common and well-understood  in the south-eastern United States, specifically Florida, Georgia, South Carolina and maybe others in that region. The meaning and usage of "waiting for you" and "wait on you" is identical. "Waiting for" is standard usage in the Northeastern U.S., and many other states too.

Comment: You won't hear it in English (i.e. England).

Comment: @Lightness: ... except maybe if you're listening to the [Rolling Stones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waiting_on_a_Friend).

Comment: @PeterShor: And then all bets are off, frankly :)

Comment: The answers here ignore a slight difference between these two usages (based on my experience).  I am omitting "to wait on" in the sense of a waiter's job. To wait for means one is waiting for something to physically arrive or happen. To wait on means that one is prepared to take subsequent actions but must wait until an action or arrival external to one's control has taken place. For example "I am waiting for Mia to bring more pickled herring" vs. "I'm ready to start cooking but I'm waiting on Mia to get here with the pickled herring." The latter has a sense of "depending on" something.

Comment: My colleagues from Colorado almost always say "wait on"

Answer (score 7):

*Wait on* has numerous meanings. In the OP’s example, it means, in the words of the OED’s definition, ‘remain in one place in expectation of’, in other words, *wait for.* The OED’s citations supporting this sense range from 1694 to 1984. The OED gives no indication of regional bias, but I wouldn’t say the use was ‘widely spread’. As for ambiguity, most of the time context removes it, and I would say it would generally do so in this case.

Answer (score 5):

"Wait on" as a synonym for "wait for" is something I've heard much more in US English than British English, but it is used in that sense.  They're pretty much synonymous.  And yes, you're right that the sentence "*your sister is waiting on you*" is ambiguous, and so it's probably best to avoid using the colloquial "wait on" for this meaning.

Answer (score 4):

I think to a considerable extent the choice of preposition is regional, stylistic, or simply arbitrary, as other answers indicate. *But* in the UK at least, whereas *I'm waiting for John* is much more common than *...on John*, there's a difference in how we add more detail...

> *I'm waiting* **on** *John [**doing** something]*
>
> *I'm waiting* **for** *John [**to do** something]*

...so it's always *I'm waiting on John arriving* or *I'm waiting for John to arrive*, never the reverse.

If it's obvious what we're actually waiting for John to do, we often omit it - particularly if we're just waiting for him to *arrive*. But as mentioned elsewhere, even Brits are likely to use **on**, not **for** in respect of computer code waiting **on** a status flag (changing in value, which we invariably omit).

Comment: I think this is important to mention. Especially the programming comment. You can see and hear it a lot when people say "I'm waiting on this code to be deployed". Even though "for" sounds perfectly acceptable I do notice the difference between waiting on and waiting for

Comment: Historically speaking, ***code*** isn't something people have often waited for / on, so I did a Google Books search for [*waiting **for** the **book** to be (published, written, whatever*).](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22waiting+for+the+book+to+be%22) Plenty of those, but as expected, not a single one for the same text using ***on*** rather than ***for***. Programmers aren't noted for their (natural) language skills in the first place, *and* I believe it's the kind of job where non-native speakers are more likely to work.

Comment: Do you have any sources about using "on" more in British English? I don't use it even when interacting with programmers but I always thought of it as one of the modern and unfortunate inventions of the language. Your answer caught my eye because of mention that in the UK "on" is used in day-to-day interactions..

Comment: @Moseleyi: I'm not sure what you're getting at. The preposition usage *We're waiting **on** John* (we will proceed when John arrives) is virtually unknown in BrE, whereas it's actually just [very uncommon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=waiting+on+John%2Cwaiting+for+John&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwaiting%20on%20John%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwaiting%20for%20John%3B%2Cc0) in AmE. Perhaps because there are more non-native Anglophones in the US, I dunno. The "computer status flag" usage is completely different though, imho.

Comment: (Perhaps the BrE aversion to using ***on*** in such contexts is because we still remember the old days when at least *some* of us had ***butlers and other servants*** to wait ***on*** us! :)

Answer (score 4):

I have lived in Texas longer (22 years) than I've lived anywhere else (IA, IL, NH, CA...) and Texas is the only place I've noticed people say "waitin' on" when they mean "waiting for." In fact, I searched for these two phrases today because yesterday at Walmart after I'd swiped my card at the register, the terminal said, "Waiting on cashier..." I thought it was funny that this regionalism had made it into a display terminal. Does the argument that "everyone says that these days" mean that it's OK to say "10 items or less," too? Nope, still wrong.

I would be interested to know from our northern contributors if they see the same message at their Walmart when they swipe their card.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that in the Queen's English, *to wait on* suggests *to serve*, not *to wait for*. Don't overlook the fact that English is the language of England, not that of the US.

Comment: And yet if I were to stop random people on the street and ask them what the language of America was, I'd expect "English" to be a pretty common answer.

Comment: Oh, please, aedia λ. Sure, English began in England, but it is now spoken in many other places, the U.S. being one of them.  As for the subject under discussion, "wait on" used in the sense of "wait for" is distinctly not mainstream U.S. English.

Comment: I agree. Such as "To wait on hand and foot" https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36384/origin-of-waited-on-hand-and-foot

Comment: What? Of course English is the language of the US, just another dialect than that of the UK. Or what would you say the language of the US is?

Comment: In British dictionaries as well as American, 'wait on' as a substitute for 'wait for' is legitimised. I agree that it's probably not most Brits' more idiomatic variant.

Comment: When saying English is not the language of the US, I think Robert meant that English is not the official language. (The US doesn't have an official language)

Answer (score 2):

I love and lament the opinions of certain contributors to this board that English from England is more pure (and therefore more correct) than the English from colonials.  Anyone who has done research into how language changes in the mother country vs. her colonies knows that precisely the opposite is true - that linguistic change in colonies tends to proceed slower than in the mother country.

Regarding "wait for" versus "wait on" and the assertion by @Lightness-Races-in-Orbit that no one in England would use "wait on" except Mick Jagger, I would point out William Shakespeare (a famous Englishman) used it all the time.

In fact, searching for these terms in the online Shakespeare concordance http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org, which shows you where and how many times the Bard used a certain word, reveals that although the great man used "wait for" four times (and "await for" once), he used "wait on" 16 times and "wait upon" 22 times.  This is a whopping victory for the pedigree of "wait on" made even more whopping if "wait upon" is included.

I also draw readers' attention to German "warten auf", which means "to wait on / for" something and the fact that "auf" is cognate with English "on".  That German and English were the same language many hundreds of years ago is also evidence that "wait on" is the older form, and that "wait for" is the upstart.

In conclusion "wait on" has just as much of a claim to "correctness" as "wait for".  Use whichever you want, and know that if you use "wait on" then you are using the language of Shakespeare. Of course you should also know that nowadays "wait for" is more common and more formal.  If that is important to you, then go with the upstart.

Comment: guest speaker, how long ago was Shakespeare? Hardly modern and up to date.

Comment: Many of Shakespeare's "wait on" and "wait upon" are in the "serve / attend so" sense. This question is about the usage of "wait on" in the _other_ sense, so you need to look at more than just a string search.

Answer (score 2):

I am from Texas and I would say that "wait on" is used more commonly than "wait for" in this region at least.  I have also lived in other parts of the south and California and I have never experienced anyone not understanding what was meant when I said "wait on".

I would argue that context, like in numerous languages is important and relevant.

There are plenty of phrases and idioms in the English language that don't translate literally so it seems that, at times, focus should be placed on accepted use and not pedagogy.

Also, with respect to @guestspeaker's comments above about Shakespeare and @Tristan's response, it is clear that @guestspeaker was making a point about how American English is arguably more "pure" than British English despite what others have argued.  So, the fact that Shakespeare is "hardly up-to-date" is actually exactly the point @guestspeaker was making.

Comment: More "pure", or just unnecessary considering that wait for is used and understood widely?

Answer (score 2):

"Wait on" was standard in England in the 18C:  Dr. Johnson consistently uses it, or at least Boswell represents him as doing so.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Ngrams ("wait on, wait for")](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wait+on%2Cwait+for&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows the two phrases comparable up to 1700, and since then "wait on" getting progressively less common and "wait for" more so. It doesn't appear to show any significant difference in British and American usage since 1800.

This search does not exclude the other sense of "wait on", so the 10:1 prevalence of "wait for" it shows for 2000 is clearly significantly lower than the ratio of uses with the meaning you are interested in.

"Waiting on" is not a phrase I would ever use in this sense. I think that without context the sentence is indeed ambiguous.

Comment: Interestingly, one of the early hits for “wait on” in Google's English corpus is a [dictionary](http://books.google.com/books?id=PCtWAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA2-PA11&dq=%22wait+on%22&hl=en&ei=72WPTsvXA4PItAag9439Dw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=%22wait%20on%22&f=false) which suggests that “wait on” specifically means serve; I'm [not sure](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/un-serviteur-attendait-il-autrefois-a-son-maitre) about the significance of *attendre* being listed as a possible translation in French.

Comment: @ Gilles: indeed the first meaning (XI century) of the French *attendre* was: *look after, tend to* (from  latin *attendere*).  This meaning has been lost in modern French though, but has survived in the English *attend on/upon* which, I think, is still used as meaning *wait on/serve*.

Comment: @Laure:  Do you really mean *attend on*?  I would use *attend to*.  At any rate.  There's clearly a significant semantic relationship between the two senses, that *attendre*=wait (for) but *attendere*=wait (on)/serve.  Fascinating.  I would assume the relationship is that someone who serves you spends a lot of time waiting to see what you need.  But we don't really have dedicated servants waiting in the other room for us anymore, do we?

Comment: @ThePopMachine: one attends *to* something but attends *on* someone, and yes it connotes servants or courtiers. "Attend on" can also mean "visit" -- but probably not since Jane Austen's time. If you attend to someone, it generally means that you're doing something to them. Dealing with bedpans comes to mind, for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

It's commonly used in Computer Science; you *wait on a mutex* (A "mutex" is an object that regulates Mutual Exclusion)

Comment: I thought this usage is justified because there is a _place_ in the code where you wait for the semaphore (or monitor, or whatever)

Comment: @belisarius: Interesting angle. Your program can wait on a line of code. I think that this usage is more to do with computing inheriting Americanisms including the more general "wait on", though.

Answer (score 0):

According to [bab.la](http://en.bab.la/wording/), "to wait for" is a lot more common than "to wait on". (43% vs. 3%.)

Answer (score 0):

IMO this exemplifies the erosion of semantic precision as a result of sloppy common usage.

When I was a lad, we were taught that *wait on* is to be used only when *to serve* is meant; it was never correct to use *wait on* as a substitute for *wait for*.  I notice, however, that this distinction is disappearing in American usage, particularly in the west.  But I see it in both written and spoken usage in all regions.  As some have stated here, though, *wait on* is rarely used for *wait for* in British or other non-US usage.

The Computer Science use of *wait on* is sloppy.  You are in fact waiting FOR the mutex to become free; you are in no sense serving the mutex.  I, for one, only use *wait on* when I mean *to serve*.

Answer (score 0):

Both are acceptable. A waitress waiting on a customer in a restaurant means exactly the same thing as a mother waiting on a child's response to a question. The inference is standing ready in a state of suspension pending some future activity.  The server stands ready awaiting instructions from the table.

Comment: Subjective. For example, I don't find "waiting on" to be acceptable.

Comment: No. A mother waiting on/for [a child's response to a question] is awaiting [that child's response to that question]. A waitress waiting on [a customer] is not awaiting [that customer] (though she may be awaiting the customer's order; but she's still waiting on the customer long after she's received that).

Answer (score -1):

Use "wait for" and you will be correct much more often. The only reason I can think of to use "wait on" is if you're telling someone where to wait, such as "on" a railway platform, or "on" a particular street corner. "Wait for Ted on the corner of sixth and main." You wait "for" the event, while positioned "on" a location.

Comment: Considering other answers here, the only reason I can think of for using "wait on" is if speaking American English.