# Word for task that is "blocked" on another task, without negative connotation?

Tags: synonyms

When describing a task that isn't running, and can't yet be started, because one or more previous tasks haven't been completed, how can that task be concisely described?

The best I have is "blocked", but

- It has a bit of a negative connotation
- It sounds a bit technical to me

Comment: impeded, or repressed  maybe

Comment: Would inactive do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The former task is *waiting on* or *dependent upon* or *contingent upon* the latter task's completion. However, consider a [past ELU question involving "wait on"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44452/wait-on-vs-wait-for).

Side note: in many technical domains, such as software development, *block* is perfectly normal, and largely free of negative connotation:

> Once called, this procedure blocks on an input signal from the device.

(I use this often enough that I would have thought little of using it in an everyday context, until I read your question. I might hang out with too many geeks.)

Comment: _waiting on_ sounds promising; If you can add reference/citation, it will help you get up-votes.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the word "[***queued***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/queued)"; according to the free dictionary it already has a definition used in the computer world to mean precisely what you are trying to mean. For instance, if you are describing a process that is waiting on another process without going into detail as to why it is waiting, you can simply say "That process is currently *queued*," or "That process is in the *queue*." I know that in an application I use for processing database changes this is the word that is used.